# How to build an ellipsoid in a ten-dimensional space?

Tags: r, ellipse

I have two sets of points in the ten-dimensional space (or 2 data frames with 1000 rows and 10 columns). I need to construct two 95% confidence ellipsoids and calculate intersection volume between them. Maybe someone can help me?

The first set of points is *a* and there are only two variables in ellipse construction, but I need 10:

```
a <- read.csv("Y:/1.csv", header=FALSE, sep=";")
library("car")
x <- a$V1
y <- a$V2
with(a, dataEllipse(x, y, level=0.95, fill=TRUE, fill.alpha=0.1))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik3sm.png)

or another way I know to build the confidence ellipse for 2-dimensional space:

```
library("ggplot2")
x <- a$V1
y <- a$V2
qplot(data = a, x, y) + stat_ellipse()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHicc.png)
I can't find some tools to construct ellipsoids in the 10-dimensional space and calculate intersection volume.

Comment: It would be wiser if you cite/specify visualizations for lower dimensions before the 10-dim'l hyperspace problem.

Comment: The common solution for such tasks is to use some dimensionality reduction technic first. For example, PCA `princomp`.  Then you will be able to solve your problem as 2-dimensional (with some loss of variation/information of course). Will it suit your aim?

Comment: Istrel, thank you for your advise, but, unfortunately, no. I tried, but I lose too many important information

Comment: TSNE would be an alternative.